# C++ strategy for storing global std::string label with getter and setter

Tags: c++, string, static, global

In a C++ project I'm working on, I need to keep track of a label. The label simply stores a `std::string` that is appended to results written to various files so that the results can be mapped to a particular *phase* of the implemented algorithms.

Here are the requirements of the mechanism for keeping track of the label:

- All translation units need access to this label
- Label must be able to be modified during runtime
- Need to control access to the label via getter/setter functions
- Always need exactly 1 label

This is not hard to implement.  But, nonetheless, I'm raising the question here because I suspect this is something commonly done --- or, at least, very similar to things commonly done.

The best solution I can think of is to have a class such as the following, and then just include the interface everywhere:

```
class Label {    
public:
    static std::string get();
    static int set(std::string s);
private:
    static std::string label;
};

std::string Label::get() { return label; }

int Label::set(std::string s) {
    if( /* OK to change to "s" */ ) {
        label = s;
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

std::string Label::label = "";
```

Because there's always exactly 1 of these labels, it seems like there ought to be a better solution than creating a class. Any suggestions?

Comment: static member functions can't be `const` as there is no `this`

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum Thanks.  Question amended correspondingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no need for a class here and recommend using free functions and a namespace. You have the same scoping semantics but without all of the decorations such as `static`. They also allow you to keep internals private just as you would with a class. A few minor changes and your code ends up like the following.

**Header**

```
namespace Label
{    
    std::string get();
    // only require a copy when necessary and allow rvalues.
    int set(const std::string& s); 
};
```

**Implementation**

```
namespace // unnamed namespace is generally recommended over using static
{
    std::string label;
}

std::string Label::get() { return label; }

int Label::set(const std::string& s)
{
    if( /* OK to change to "s" */ )
    {
        label = s;
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: The downside to this approach is you can no longer do Label::set(""), but have to do Label().set(""), or otherwise provide an instance of the Label class, without which you can't call the members.

Comment: _"no longer do Label::set(""), but have to do Label().set("")"_ - uh I believe you have that backwards. For the love of Geppetto why would you want to do `Label().set("");`? It's a whole extra one byte character longer! You asked for solutions other than creating a class. If you _absolutely_ need an instance then add it to your list of requirements and create a class.

Comment: @Jherico the point is there is no `Label` class to provide an instance of.

Comment: Wouldn't this result in different labels for different translation units though?

Comment: @juanchopanza Only if you stick the implementation in the header.

Comment: Sorry, I'd missed the change from class Label to namespace Label.

Comment: This is great. I knew there had to be a better way (not using a class).  Thanks for this.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Please explain what you mean in your code comment `and allow rvalues`. Are you saying that by declaring a reference parameter as const, you can then pass an rvalue as an argument?  (If so, I didn't know that.)  I guess the lifetime of the rvalue is extended through the lifetime of the consuming function?

Comment: Yes, declaring the argument as const-ref allows you to pass an rvalue as a parameter. The lifetime of the rvalue is not extended since it already lives until the end of the expression (i.e. after the function returns).

Answer (score 2):

I'd tend to wonder whether there might not be more use for a broader class, something like:

```
template <class T>
class cond_write {
    T val;
    std::function<bool()> c;
public:
    template <class Cond>
    cond_write(T const &t, Cond c): val(t), c(c) {}

    cond_write &operator=(T const &t) {
        if (c())
            val=t;
        return *this;
    }

    operator T() const { return val; }
};
```

Then you'd instantiate it with (in your case) `std::string`, and a lambda for the condition under which a write can happen.

Instead of `get` and `set`, you'd just assign to it, or use it as a T (`std::string`, in your case). For example:

```
cond_write<std::string> label("Initial label", []() { return whatever(); });

// equivalent to label.set("This might be the new label");
label="This might be the new label";

// equivalent to std::string new_label = label.get();
std::string new_label=label;
```

Comment: But only certain newer compilers support lambda functions, and some of my hosts are running older GCC versions (such as RHEL5 hosts).